# how to make an auto row grid to add content

Tags: css

i want to make a automatic grid row, but i dont know hot to do that and i need to put grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 200px); i need to put repeat() to insert a new row whenever i need a new row, there's some way to turn it automatic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzeKf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AblY3.png)

i thought to make a script to check it but i want a css way

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
}

html, body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body *{
    border: 1px solid rgb(21, 20, 20);
}
.grid{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem calc(100% - 4.375rem);
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.header{
    
}

.container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:14% 1fr;
}

.offers{
    }

.content{
    padding:10px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 200px);
    gap: 10px;

    overflow: auto;
}

.card{

}

.card:nth-of-type(7n+4){
    background-color: blue;
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid grid-template">
    <header class="header"></header>
    <div class="container">
        <aside class="offers"></aside>
        <section class="content">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML?

Comment: i did shared now

Comment: You mean like `grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 200px) auto;`